# How do I escape the while loop? c++

Tags: c++

```
void fireShip1(int Numbers2[], bool notFound, int position1, string playerOne, int numberOfSunkenShips, int numberOfShips)
{
    numberOfSunkenShips = 0;
    while (notFound = true)
    {
        cout << playerOne << ", please enter a location to fire at." << endl;
        cin >> position1;
            if (Numbers2[position1] == 0)
            {
                cout << "You missed!" << endl;
            }
            else if (Numbers2[position1] == 1)
            {
                cout << "Bullseye!" << endl;
                numberOfSunkenShips++;
                cout << "You have sunk " << numberOfSunkenShips << " ships." << endl;
                if (numberOfSunkenShips == numberOfShips)
                {
                    notFound = false;
                }
                Numbers2[position1] = 0;
                return;
            }
    }
    cout << playerOne << " has won the match!" << endl;
}
```

numberofSunkenShips doesn't get higher than 1. It needs to have the value of three in order for me to reach the "has won the match" string outside the while loop. Any help?

Comment: Did you declare **notFound** above the loop, and set it to an initial value of true?

Comment: @Lakey Its declared as a parameter of the function.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: or even better: `while (notFound)`

Comment: Use `while(true)` and then use a `break`? Or, `while (numberOfSunkenShips < numberOfShips)`

Comment: the notFound value doesn't affect the problem. numberOfSunkenShips++; doesn't seem to be working since i'm using return. Removing return allows numberOfSunkenShips++ to work, but I need to have return for another part of the program to work

Comment: Ok, just put **break** where you have **return**.  Move your **return** down to the end of the function (after your **cout** line)

Comment: I don't want to reach the cout unless numberOfSunkenShips is equal to numberOfShips. Why doesn't ++ work?

Comment: Then put a `break;` after where you have `notFound = false;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (notFound = true)
```

should be:

```
//assume you have declared notFound
while (notFound == true)
              //^^^
```

or simply:

```
while (notFound)
```